# Script# 0.8 changes in generated code

Tags: script#

I've built the latest script# source from Github and started using it in a project. It looks like the way code is generated has changed.

How do I make the compiler go back to the old way of generating code? (the 0.7.x way)

Comment: Changed AssemblyInfo.cs ScriptTemplate attribute to match the old jQuery syntax, but since "." naming has changed to "$" any projects referencing another library doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a flag to go back to the old output. The new output brings the AMD pattern for creating script modules to script# generated output, and takes advantage of it to streamline things and make generated script more consistent with accepted patterns.

First is use of the module scope to generate private types better so they are more minimizable. Specifically the whole identifier using '$' as separator is minimized, rather than being left as unminimizable because of the "."... eventually I'll be using that for private members as well.

Public types are exposed in the same way outside the module if you were using the assembly ScriptNamespace attribute previously to minimizing typically longer c# namespaces.

If you weren't using ScriptNamespace, and instead previously you were exposing type such as SomeNamespace.SomeSubnamespace.SomeType, then there is a change on the public surface area as well - the same type is now exposed as SomeModule.MyType (like you would with a ScriptNamespace = SomeModule). Every c# assembly maps to a module.

Again, this is to minimize better, as well as being in sync with patterns that most other script frameworks have adopted. Hope that provides some of the context for the change.

Was there a particular aspect of the old output that you need, rather than essentially the need to keep it the same? If you need exactly the same output as before, then 0.7.x is going to be the version to use.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

0.7.x allowed me to deploy the output js and allowed other users to re-use the lib without Script# (eg: in typescript). The dot notation made it easy and nice inside visual studio but now the $ notation is a bit strange.

The only reason I ask for 0.7.x syntax is:
1. ss.js - can we please generate code independant of ss.js (eg: only require ss.js if we use system functions)

2. ability to generate dot notation instead of $

Comment: To be honest, not 100% clear. The dot notation is very much there, for what you _intend_ to expose publicly out of a module. Only private types are hidden, but you choose what is private and public. Public types become Module.TypeName now. Don't see why there should be a TypeScript issue specifically, as a) those types you intend to expose from a module still are, and b) its JavaScript, so theoretically it should be completely possible to use it with TypeScript.

Comment: On ss.js - The generation of types depends on ss.js just like in the older version registration of types required mscorlib.js. The compiler doesn't care what ss.js contains... so theoretically there could be an ss.js containing APIs such as ss.module, and so on, implemented to use mscorlib.js functionality.

Comment: Sorry about not being clear, let me try again. In 0.7.x versions I had an output file which I could use against a web project which didn't rely on script#.

I could add /// <reference... to visual studio to get intellisense. eg: var x = SomeNamespace.SomeService();
x.SomeMethod();

With 0.8 I've added /// references to ss and the output file but I don't get the same experience.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? I've tried the fishtank example and flickr, same thing happens, no intellisense

Comment: For the sake of completeness here for anyone else coming to this question - see https://gist.github.com/4660121 for how to export a module to global namespace when not using the AMD pattern (eg. require) and getting intellisense. Would help to mark as answered :)