# Script# generated javascript file class names are seperated using dollar sign instead of dot '.'

Tags: script#

I am using a custom build of Script# which I have downloaded from the Script# website and the output javascript files being generated is having the following example of code:

```
// GeneralJS_v4.Wrappers.Elements.MyElementEventHandlers

function GeneralJS_v4$Wrappers$Elements$MyElementEventHandlers(element) {
  this._element = element;
  this._handlersMap = {};
}
```

As you can see the class name generated is `GeneralJS_v4$Wrappers$Elements$MyElementEventHandlers`.  The problem is that whenever a different project references another project, it doesn't reference them with the `$`but using the `.` sign (e.g. `GeneralJS_v4.Wrappers.Elements.MyElementEventHandlers`) and hence it gives an error of not finding the class.

Any idea why it is using the `$` for the generated class names instead of `.`?

Answer (score 0):

This same topic was covered in [Script# 0.8 changes in generated code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557863/script-0-8-changes-in-generated-code) as well.

Summary is the generated code is *now* within a script module (implemented as a function closure), and the module object has all public types hanging off of it for consumers of the module to access in line with the AMD pattern. See here for some details about the AMD pattern itself: http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/

For illustrative purposes if your assembly corresponds to the "foo" module, the resulting script will be something like:

```
define('foo', ['ss'], function(ss) {

 // GeneralJS_v4.Wrappers.Elements.MyElementEventHandlers

 function GeneralJS_v4$Wrappers$Elements$MyElementEventHandlers(element) {
   this._element = element;
   this._handlersMap = {};
 }

 var $exports = ss.module('basic', null,
   {
     MyElementEventHandlers: [ GeneralJS_v4$Wrappers$Elements$MyElementEventHandlers, GeneralJS_v4$Wrappers$Elements$MyElementEventHandlers$, null ]
   });

 return $exports;
});
```

A good example to see the generated output and varying that using the ScriptTemplate metadata attribute is the unit test - see https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/tree/cc/tests/TestCases/Basic/Simple

A caller having a reference to the `foo` module would be able to access your type as `foo.MyElementEventHandlers` i.e. with the object.member style.

For example:

```
require(['foo'], function(foo) {

  var o = new foo.MyElementEventHandlers(...);
});
```

In addition to the unit tests, this is also shown in the various samples present in the github repository which show use generated scripts with the script# AMD script loader (AroundMe sample), the much more well-known requirejs AMD loader (KOWorld sample), as well as without using the AMD pattern (FishTank sample).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am trying to get the hang of this new concept by taking a look at the samples..  The 'Scripts' folder of the AroundMe sample project and the KOWorld sample project are empty, should they be automatically generated?

Comment: Also, the `AroundMe` project has a reference to a Twitter project which was complaining of not finding the `[ScriptProperty]` attribute

Comment: You need to enable restore nuget packages on the project. Also, make sure that it's pointing to the 0.8 package.